# Swift/iOS: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException'

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm using [PageMenu](https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu) by [uacaps](https://github.com/uacaps) from Github. I added a UIViewController and a UITableViewController and set it's custom class to `FrmProfile` and `FrmProfile_Album`

[image: UIViewController]
[image: Custom class]

set it to initial viewcontroller:

[image]

UIViewController:

[image: UIViewController]
[image: Custom class]

and set outlet:

[image: outlet]

FrmProfile.swift :

```
import UIKit

class FrmProfile: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - Outlets
    @IBOutlet weak var vBase: UIView!

    // MARK: - Vars
    var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

    //MARK: - Functions
    func setPageMenu () {
        var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

        let cAlbums : FrmProfile_AlbumList = FrmProfile_AlbumList()
        cAlbums.title = "Albums"
        controllerArray.append(cAlbums)
        let cArticles : FrmProfile_ArticleList = FrmProfile_ArticleList()
        // Customize menu (Optional)
        let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
            .SelectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor.blackColor()),
            .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.whiteColor()),
            .ViewBackgroundColor(UIColor.whiteColor()),
            .SelectionIndicatorColor(cblue),
            .BottomMenuHairlineColor(UIColor(red: 204.0/255.0, green: 204.0/255.0, blue: 204.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
            .MenuHeight(40.0),
            .MenuItemWidth(90.0),
            .CenterMenuItems(true)
        ]

        // Initialize scroll menu
        pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 96.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height - 96), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

        self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
        vBase.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)

        pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }

    //MARK: - Override functions
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setPageMenu()
    }
}
```

FrmProfile_Albums.swift:

```
import UIKit

class FrmProfile_AlbumList: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    private struct Storyboard {
        static let CellReuseIdentifier = "album"
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(Storyboard.CellReuseIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "One album"
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "notes"
        return cell
    }
}
```

I added UITableViewCell identifier:

[image: identifier]

Then, when I ran my app, I get these errors:

> Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
>
> Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3505.4/UITableView.m:6540
>
> 2015-09-06 13:06:32.784 CenterBrain[541:74966] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier album - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Anyone knows how to solve this? Thanks a lot!